# Array outputs random sequence of characters instead of desired result

Tags: java, arrays, string, csv

I am attempting to write a program that will output data received from a csv file. The CSV file is composed of 28 or so strings/lines with each data in the line separated by a comma into 5 categories (Team name, League, Coaches, Division and Full Time).

I actually have a couple of issues...

1. When i run my program, i receive a random sequence of characters (such as: [Ljava.lang.String;@5e34d46a) in my coaches category instead of a name that i am expecting. Does this have something to do with it being in an array? How would i solve it.
2. The categories for each string are displayed in the output as a list, i would like to output the data of strings into a line. For example, instead of the output displaying:
   Team name: Team A
   League: Western Conference
   Coaches: [Ljava.lang.String;@1c751d58
   Division: 2
   Full Time: true

I would like it to be displayed as a line.

3. The last category of a single instance of a string in the output is attached to the first category of the next string. Like so: Full Time: trueTeam name: Team A. How would i separate this?

My Team.java code:

```
public class Team 
{
 private String name;
 private String league;
 private String[] coaches;
 private String division;
 private boolean fullTime;

 public Team(String dataLine)
 {
    String[] data = dataLine.split(",");
    this.name = data[0];

    this.coaches = getStringAsArray(data[1], ":");

    this.league = data[2];

    this.division = data[3];

    this.fullTime = data[4].equals("yes");      

 }

 public Team(){

 }

 private String[] getStringAsArray(String t, String delimiter)
 {
    String[] result = t.split(delimiter);
    return result;
 }

 private String getArrayAsString(String[] coaches)
 {

    coaches = this.getCoaches();
    String result = "";
    for(int i = 0; i<coaches.length; i++)
    {
        result += coaches[i] +" ";
    }
    result = result.trim();
    return result;
 }

 public void setName(String name)
 {
    this.name = name;
 }

 public String getName()
 {
    return this.name;
 }

 public void setCoaches(String coaches)
 {
    this.coaches = getStringAsArray(coaches, ":");
 }

 public String getCoachesAsString()
 {

    String result = getArrayAsString(coaches);
    return result;
 }

 public boolean isFullTime() {
    return fullTime;
 }

 public void setFullTime(boolean fullTime) {
    this.fullTime = fullTime;
 }

 public String getDivision() {
    return division;
 }

 public void setDivision(String division) {
    this.division = division;
 }

 public String[] getCoaches() {
    return coaches;
 }

 public void setCoaches(String[] coaches) {
    this.coaches = coaches;
 }

 public String getLeague() {
    return league;
 }

 public void setLeague(String league) {
    this.league = league;
 }

 @Override
 public String toString() {
    return "Team name: " + name + "\nLeague: " + this.league + "\nCoaches: "       + this.coaches +  "\nDivision: " + this.division + "\nFull Time: " +   this.fullTime;

 }
}
```

My StoreData.java code:

```
import shiftershape.model.Team;
import  java.util.ArrayList;

public class StoreData {
public static ArrayList<Team> teams = new ArrayList<Team>();

public static String getTeams()
{
    String s = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < teams.size(); i++){
        s += teams.get(i);

    }
    return s;
}

public static ArrayList<Team> TeamListFromArray(String[] as)
 {
     ArrayList<Team> teams = new ArrayList<Team>();
    // for( int i= 0 ; i < as.length; i++){
     for (String s: as){
        teams.add(new Team(s));
     }
     return teams;
 }

}
```

My ReadCSV.java code:

```
 import Utilities.StoreData;
 import java.io.BufferedReader;
 import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
 import java.io.FileReader;
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import shiftershape.model.Team;

 public class ReadCsv {

 public void readCsv() {

    String csvFileToRead =   "C:/Users/Fryyy/Desktop/FootballRepo/TestData/football_teams_phase1.csv";
    BufferedReader br = null;
    String line = "";

    try {

        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFileToRead));
        int i = 0;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            Team one = new Team(line);

            if(i > 0){
                 StoreData.teams.add(new Team(line));
            }else{
               i++;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (br != null) {
            try {
                br.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
 }

public static ArrayList<Team> getTeams() {
    return StoreData.teams;
  }

   public static void setTeams(ArrayList<Team> teams) {
    StoreData.teams = teams;
  }
 }
```

My FootballC.java code:

```
import Utilities.StoreData;
import shiftershape.model.Team;

public class FootballC {
 public static void main(String[] args)
{



    ReadCsv junk = new ReadCsv();
    junk.readCsv();
    System.out.println(StoreData.getTeams());


  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`System.out.println(StoreData.getTeams());` will call `toString()` on String[]

try this:

```
for (String s : StoreData.getTeams()) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Ljava.lang.String;@5e34d46a) is the resource code for an object when printed to standard out. In this case being a string, so somewhere it looks like you're printing an array instead of the value within the array, causing the resource ID to be shown instead of the values within, as Java doesn't print array contents by default.

Answer (score 0):

[Ljava.lang.String;@1c751d58 is the String version of an array. Arrays don't have a nice toString() method. If you used Lists in stead of Arrays it will print better.

The quick conversion of an array to a list is Arrays.asList(array);